# net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET on uploading images

Tags: node.js, file-upload, upload, fetch

I am working on localhost. while updating/uploading image as buffer on the database, it is failing with error **"net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET"**.

The file is not too large as well. 
So what is the solution to this? I am very much confused.

html part>>>

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="customFile" accept="image/*" ata-max-size="50000" multiple>
```

js part>>>

```
        var imgform = document.querySelector('#customFile')
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("image", imgform.files[0])
        fetch(`/posts/image/${postId}`
                ,{
                    method: 'patch',
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token
                    },
                    body: formData
                }
                    ).then((response)=>{
                        console.log(response.status);
                    })
```

Comment: Show server-side code

Comment: server side code is also simple :

router.post('/ads/image/:postId/', auth, upload.single('image'), async(req,res)=>{
// console.log(req.file.buffer);

var ad = await Ad.findOne({_id: req.params.postId, owner:req.user.id})

var imageBuffer = await sharp(req.file.buffer).png().resize({
width:250,
fit: sharp.fit.cover,
position: sharp.strategy.entropy
}).toBuffer()
imgId = req.params.imageId
ad.image1 = imageBuffer

Comment: @theblue5.o Please put the code into the question, formatted as code.

Answer (score 0):

I've also been searching for what could cause this, and it looks like it might be something from the server, in the meantime, one thing I did that helped was to add `keepalive: true` to the fetch methods like so:

```
 var imgform = document.querySelector('#customFile')
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("image", imgform.files[0])
    fetch(`/posts/image/${postId}`
            ,{
                method: 'patch',
                keepalive: true,
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token
                },
                body: formData
            }
                ).then((response)=>{
                    console.log(response.status);
                })
```